# Onsen UI sliding menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have a menue like this:

```
   <ons-navigator animation="slide" var="myNavigator">
    <ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.html" main-page="link/to/some/page.html" side="left"
                         var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
       </ons-sliding-menu>

       <ons-template id="menu.html">
          <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
             <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>
             <ons-list class="menu-list">
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('link/to/some/page.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                   Home
                </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('link/to/some/other/page.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                   Home
                </ons-list-item>
     </ons-list>
          </ons-page>
       </ons-template>
   </ons-navigator>
```

after navigating to "link/to/some/other/page.html", I have a `$scope.myNavigator.pushPage('anotherpage', {});`

operation. This also works.
But after I performed the *pushpage* operation, I am not able to use the menu any more. I have to do a *popPage* before.

A page looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="someNiceController">
   <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
         <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
               <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
         </div>
         <div class="center">{{title}}</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
        My nice content
   </ons-page>
</div>
```

I think there is a problem with the structure of my page... 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should put the sliding menu outside the navigator.

The content inside the navigator will be replaced by another page when you push, so the sliding menu in your example will disappear when you use `pushPage()`.

The following code shows how you can use a sliding menu together with a navigator:

```
<ons-sliding-menu
                  main-page="main.html"
                  menu-page="menu.html"       
                  side="left"
                  max-slide-distance="250px"
                  var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="main.html">
  <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <ons-button onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html')">Push</ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="page2.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 2</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <ons-button onclick="myNavigator.popPage()">Pop</ons-button>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
      Some option
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
      Another option      
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>
```

Here you can see it in action:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/ogXGeV

Comment: Thank You. This works for the menu, but leads to some other issues.... For example:
In my angular code, I set some styles for buttons and so on. Those elements are not found any more. Example command: document.getElementById('btn_apply')

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working sliding menu in Onsen UI. Two changes you should make is to put the `sliding-menu` element is outside of the navigator, and to reference it with a variable, `var="menu"`. Using a variable simplifies your script. Click below for a simple example.

```js
ons.bootstrap();
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <ons-sliding-menu main-page="main.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="left" max-slide-distance="250px" var="menu">
  </ons-sliding-menu>
  <ons-template id="main.html">
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Page 1</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <br>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <ons-button onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html')">Next Page</ons-button>
        <ons-button onclick="menu.toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</ons-button>
      </div>
    </ons-navigator>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Page 2</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <br>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <ons-button onclick="myNavigator.popPage()">Back</ons-button>
      </div>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
  <ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
        First option
      </ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
        Second option
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-template>
</body>
```